# What is a single-word semantic term for "fluid height"?

Tags: css, naming-conventions

I've always interpreted "fluid" web pages as being a term where a percentage of the page or container width is used.

Is there an equivalent term for talking about percentages of the height of a page or container?

This is for CSS class naming purposes.

Comment: I never heard it. Maybe because it's far less common to fit a page vertically in the screen.

Comment: Yes, I think the only reason people talk about "fluid" in terms of width is because height is normally fluid by default. Items are usually only as tall as the content it contains unless you tell it not to.